# window.open failed on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript

I am write browser extension but on microsoft edge, I am not able to open my ViewDetails.html on button click.
`ViewDetails.html` : this file present in my current directory.

This is open function call.

```
var myWindow = window.open("ViewDetails.html", "Details", "height=600,width=1200,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
```

> open function return : *SCRIPT16389: Unspecified error

How can i resolved this issue...

Comment: we need more information, window.open() works fine on edge

Comment: Yes, It's work fine for URL. But here i am try to access my local HTMl page.

Answer (score 2):

Hei,

The nice way to check if the functionality supported by a browser is to check on "[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/)"; as I see here at the moment the "support info" for the `window.open()` function on the **Edge** browser is stated as **unknown**.

Here's the link: https://caniuse.com/#search=window.open

Hope I could help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try delete the last " in your code..?

```
var myWindow = window.open("ViewDetails.html", "Details", "height=600,width=1200,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");"
```

Into

```
var myWindow = window.open("ViewDetails.html", "Details", "height=600,width=1200,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes");
```

Comment: That was my mistake while writing issue. Not in code